# Skip HTTP Header from GET request

Tags: node.js, arduino, esp8266

I need help with my project.
Here is my code:

```
void ConexaoServer(){
    uint8_t buffer[1024] = {0};

    if (wifi.createTCP(HOST_NAME, HOST_PORT)) {
        Serial.print("Conexao com o Host OK!\r\n");
    } else {
        Serial.print("Conexao com o Host com ERRO!\r\n");
    }

    char *ComandoGET = "GET /teste HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: SmartHome\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
    wifi.send((const uint8_t*)ComandoGET, strlen(ComandoGET));

    uint32_t len = wifi.recv(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 10000);
    if (len > 0) {
        Serial.print("Received:[");
        for(uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            Serial.print((char)buffer[i]);
        }
        Serial.print("]\r\n\r\n");
    }
}
```

And I receive from Node.js in Serial

```
Received:[HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 4
ETag: W/"4-wArb1VtkpsN6In8g50pGNw"
Date: Wed, 31 Aug 2016 01:26:41 GMT
Connection: close

Luiz]
```

But I want to receive just `Received:[Luiz]`. How i can do this?

Comment: Why not perform the HTTP request from node (js land) itself? That way you don't have to parse HTTP manually...

Comment: @mscdex how i do that in Node.js? Here is my code in app.js

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/teste', function(req, res) {
 res.send('Hello World!');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, "localhost", function () {
 var host = server.address().address;
 var port = server.address().port;

 console.log('Exemplo na URL http://%s:%s', host, port);
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the double newlines (`\r\n\r\n`) and use the chars after that.

```cpp
char payload[1024] = "";
char *pl = strstr((char*)buffer, "\r\n\r\n");
if (pl != NULL)
{
    strcpy(payload, pl+4);
    Serial.println(payload);
}
```